# how to set the width and height of a new window that is opened with window.open

Tags: javascript

I have a button that opens a new window.

```
 window.open(newUrl, '_blank', 'width=370,height=220')
```

I need the size of the new window to depend on the size of the screen. Maybe I can set them as a percentage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two properties being screen.height and screen.width, and multiply them by any percentage you'd like.

```
const width = document.documentElement.clientWidth * yourWidthPercentageHere;
const height = document.documentElement.clientHeight * yourHeightPercentageHere;
window.open(newUrl, '_blank', 'width=' + width + ',height=' + height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set the window size as a percentage, like this:

```js
window.open(newUrl, '_blank', 'width="100%",height="100%"')
```